# dovecot + squirrelmail: misconfigured mail folders

Tags: email-server, dovecot

On the mail server I have been trying to set up, I've configured postfix to deliver mail to the virtual user `user1` (with email address `user1@example.com`) to the file `/var/mail/vhosts/user1@example.com/mail`. I did this by setting:

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cfg
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtmailmaps.conf
```

and:

```
# /etc/postfix/virtmailmaps.conf
# ...
query = SELECT destination FROM virtusers WHERE email='%s'
```

The mysql database has the `virtusers` table:

```
+----+----------+-------------------+------------------------+
| id | password |        email      |      destination       |
+----+----------+-------------------+------------------------+
|  1 | ...      | user1@example.com | user1@example.com/mail |
+----+----------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

Now, for dovecot I have set:

```
mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/vhosts:INBOX=/var/mail/vhosts/%u/mail
```

and:

```
password_query = SELECT email as user, password FROM virtusers WHERE email='%u';
```

This I clearly hacked together to work, but when I access squirrelmail and send/delete emails, the folders `Drafts`, `Trash` and `Sent` are created in `/var/mail/vhosts` and its contents are shared between all the virtual users.

So, it seems I haven't set some home option correctly, but I don't quite clearly understand what the configuration file options are doing (in postfix, dovecot and squirrelmail) and how it all meshes together. For example, I have already set:

```
# /etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext
userdb {
  driver = static
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%u
}
```

How do I fix this so that the `Drafts`, `Trash` and `Sent` directories are in each user's home directory `/var/mail/vhosts/user1@example.com/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you have

```
mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/vhosts/%u:INBOX=/var/mail/vhosts/%u/mail
```

i.e. you don't currently have the username `%u` variable in the `mbox` path, only in the `INBOX` path.

Comment: Ah! Is that it. I remember trying that before and it not working so maybe I made a mistake. I've currently switched to maildir format so I can't confirm this yet, but thanks!